# Ruby: If Values in a hash are equal if statement. Need a hint if possilbe?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, hash

Hi there: Ruby Beginner.

So I'm working on a little exercise.
I have this

```
donation = {
    "Randy" => 50,
    "Steve" => 50,
    "Eddie" => 9,
    "Bill" => 12
}

donation.max_by.first { |name, money| money.to_i }
name, money  = donation.max_by { |name, money| money.to_i }
puts "#{name} donated the most, at $#{money}!"
```

But there's a little bug. "Randy" and "Steve" both donated the max, but it outputs "Randy" (because they're the first in key in the for hash, I assume?) and they get all the credit!

I'm thinking the way to go is, I need an IF ELSE statement; IF any? of the "money" values are equal, it moves on. Else, it puts the statement.

SO i guess I am wondering how to compare values?

Comment: `donation.method(:max_by).owner #=> Enumerable` tells you where [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) is defined. You see there are 4 forms of the method, two that take a block and return an object, two that return an enumerator. Since `max_by` has no block in your use case, `enum = donation.max_by #=> #<Enumerator: {"Randy"=>50, "Steve"=>50, "Eddie"=>9, "Bill"=>12}:max_by>`. Then you have `enum.first  { |name, money| money.to_i }`, which returns the first element of the enumerator for which `money.to_i` is *logically true*
...

Comment: ...That is `enum.first #=>  ["Randy", 50] ` because `money.to_i` is always logically `true`.  Therefore, `donation.max_by.first { |name, money| money.to_i }` returns  `["Randy", 50]`, but since there is no variable to collect it and no method for which it is the receiver Ruby scratches her head and orders it to be processed by the *garbage collector*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, `max_by` returns the first key that has the maximum value. It actually takes a parameter that is the number of elements to return, so doing something like `.max_by(donation.size)` will return the hash in descending order and you could then go through the elements until the value doesn't match the first (max) value.

But, there's a couple of simpler ways to go about it. If you just want to print the information as you go, one way would be to just iterate through the hash looking for values that match the max value:

```rb
mx = donation.values.max
puts "The following people donated the most ($#{mx}):"
donation.each { |k, v| puts k if v == mx }
```

Output:

```
The following people donated the most ($50):
Randy
Steve
```

You could also use `.select` to match for the max value, which preserves the hash form:

```rb
mx = donation.values.max
donation.select { |k, v| v == mx }
 => {"Randy"=>50, "Steve"=>50}
```

**EDIT**
Per the follow-up comment, if you use `.select` to capture the result as a new hash, you can then use conditional logic, loops, etc., to process the data from there. As a very simple example, suppose you want a different message if there's only one top donor vs. multiple:

```rb
mx = donation.values.max
max_donors = donation.select { |k, v| v == mx }
if max_donors.size > 1
  puts "The following people donated the most ($#{mx}):"
  max_donors.keys.each { |name| puts name }
elsif max_donors.size == 1
  name, money = max_donors.first
  puts "#{name} donated the most, at $#{money}!"
else
  puts 'No one donated!'
end
```

Comment: Oh, okay, cool Thank you for explaining! So, bear with me? If I made a new hash that now had the two highest with two keys and matching high values in it, is there a way to write an if statement that if there's more than one key in the new hash, the statement is false and moves on? Or is this just a ridiculous idea? I am definitely still a beginner so feel free to let me know if this is just bad practice.

Comment: No, not ridiculous; that's what application logic is for. I'll edit the answer with just a quick example, but I suggest you give it a go and try different things to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Amazing. I was close! I knew to use > and ==, but i was struggling with .size. Thank you for all your help and explanations!

Answer (score 2):

### Select Elements Matching Highest Value

There's more than one way to identify and extract multiple elements that share a maximum value. Based on the semantics you're trying to communicate in your code, one working example is as follows:

```
max_amt = donation.max_by(&:last)[-1]
donation.select { |name, amt| amt == max_amt }
#=> {"Randy"=>50, "Steve"=>50}
```

First, we capture the maximum value from the *donations* Hash. Next, the [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) method passes the name and amount of each donation into the block, which returns the Hash elements for which the comparison to the maximum value is truthy. Inside the block, each amount is compared to the maximum value found in the original Hash, allowing all matching key/value pairs to be returned when more than one of them contains a value equal to the *max_amt*.